# Sharepoint Site Template: How do I set the default Site Template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-branding

I created a subsite using the "Publishing Site with Workflow" site template in Sharepoint.

I then created a page in the subsite using a custom page layout and set that page as the default page for the subsite.

I then exported this subsite as a site template by going to this page under my subsite.
http://domain/mysubsite/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

I checked the include content button when creating the template

This template works great, i.e., when I create a new subsite (mysubsite2) using it the site has a default page with my custom page layout as intended.

The problem is that if I try to create a third subsite under mysubsite2 the only site template available by default is the "Publishing Site with Workflow".

I can go back to the root of the site collection and tell it to allow users to only see my custom site template when creating a site and inherit this down through all subsites but ideally the subsite would automatically be created with a custom template I created through the earlier described process.  How do I modify/create a site template which uses itself as the default template for all subsites? What do I need to set in the onenet.xml "AvailableWebTemplates"? How do I refer to my custom site template.

Answer (score 2):

How did you install the site template, did you use stsadm.exe -o [addtemplate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261822.aspx)? I have created site templates this week, and to use them, I ran stsadm. When I create a new subsite, my site template appears in the list.

As a plan B, you could use stsadm.exe -o [createwebsite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262594.aspx), passing it the name of the site template. To get the name of the template, use stsadm.exe -o [enumtemplates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263342.aspx). This will list all the site templates available. You should see your custom template appear, with a name like "*GLOBAL*#5" or something like that.

Use that "*GLOBAL*#5" name in the params for createwebsite.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your tip about enumtemlates should help. I'll try to utilize that tomorrow.  How did you create your site template? Using savetmpl.aspx or did you copy another template and modify it?

Comment: I saved the template using savetmpl.aspx.